# How do I get php curl to run on my apache2.x Development server?

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-7, configuration

Before I begin, I will add that I've spent much time googling this and have attempted several solutions none of which have worked.

System Info:

Windows 7 Professional (x86, 32 bit )

Apache2 up and running C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\

PHP 5.3.8 C:\Program Files\PHP Also works.
manually configured httpd.conf to enable php, note that php is working, except for curl.

I have enabled curl in my php.ini C:\Program Files\PHP\php.ini

This is near the end of my php.ini

```
[PHP]   
extension_dir = "ext"  
[PHP_CURL]  
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Note also that the file C:\Program Files\PHP\ext\php_curl.dll exists!

I have restarted the apache server and yet curl still does not function.

a quick test.php file:

```
<?php 

$curl_conn = curl_init();

?>
```

note that I have both php start and end tags correct stackoverflow just isn't showing the start php tag.
puts out:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in E:\path\to_project\test.php on line 3

I have now spent 3 hours trying to get curl to work, google has no helped, most of the solutions seem to involve making sure that the extension=module line in php.ini is not commented out, and as you can see above it is not commented out so that advice doesn't seem to help me.

Any ideas would be appreciated as this is rather frustrating.
Thanks!

Comment: Try to see if this guide helps: http://www.tonyspencer.com/2003/10/22/curl-with-php-and-apache-on-windows/

Comment: try: `extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\PHP\ext"`

Answer (score 1):

You should add "C:\PHP" to the server's PATH environment variable:

1. Right-click on My Computer, choose Properties
2. Flip to the Advanced tab
3. Click the Environment Variables button
4. Double-click the Path variable in the list of System variables.
5. Either add "C:\PHP;" to the beginning or ";C:\PHP" to the end (sans quotes, not both).
6. Restart your computer for it to take effect.

Thanks to:

http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/install_and_configure.php

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread has long been closed, but for anyone like myself who encounters this problem subsequently, for me, the answer turned out to be a DIFFERENT copy of the `php.ini` file was being loaded than what I thought. I was editing the `php.ini` file in my PHP 5.4.3 directory, and there is another copy of the `php.ini` file that resides in the Apache directory - identical as far as I could tell from a quick glance.

De-commenting the `extension=php_curl.dll` line IN THE RIGHT FILE, the Apache folder, enabled the curl function for me.

Jeff S.

Answer (score 0):

Have you copied cURL dependency files:

```
  libeay32.dll
  ssleay32.dll
```

to `C:\Windows\System32` folder?

It could be that PHP cannot find these two files to run cURL extension.

Comment: I'm attempting to do as you suggest, but this is ridiculous, ssleay32.dll isn't in the lib curl binary package on curl.haxx.se, but I copied libeay32.dll into C:\Windows. I restarted apache but that didn't work. I also copied libssl32.dll from the libcurl package to C:\Windows assuming it might be a replacement for ssleay32.dll in later curl versions. But still no dice!

Comment: both files should be in PHP root folder. Have a look in phpinfo() script page to see if cURL is loaded and also check apache error log file to see if any relevant PHP Warning.

Comment: I don't know why I didn't check this before, but actually, both libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are in the root of my php install. I checked the apache error log and the access.log file. The only reference to php is "[Sat Oct 15 13:49:10 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8 configured -- resuming normal operations" However, I still can't call curl from php. I get the same error described in my original post.

Comment: I tried removing `ssleay32.dll` from `C:\Windows\System32` folder, and I got the same error you got: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in ...`, but it does work when I copy the dll file back and restart Apache. Although both dll files are in PHP folder, you need to manually copy them to `System32` folder. Look in `php.info()` script to see if `cURL` is loaded properly.